# Set of optimal solutions for a linear programs

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the linear program: minimize $z = x_{1} - x_{2}$, $x_{1}, x_{2}\geq 0$

subject to: $-x_{1} + x_{2}\leq 1$
                                        ,  $x_{1} - 2x_{2}\leq 2$

Derive an expression for the set of optimal solutions, and show that the set is unbounded.

I was able to get the optimal solution for this problem is $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})= (0,1,0,4)^{T}$. However, this is a unique solution (checked by Excel's Add-in Solver). So I don't understand why the problem asks for a SET of optimal solutions? Please help if you can.

Comment: Something is wrong in your description. The model only involves two variables ($x_1$ and $x_2$) but you list a solution with four variables.

Comment: I included the slack variable. Otherwise, the solution is the first two elements: $(x_{1}, x_{2})= (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)=(1.5,2.5,0,5.5)$ is another optimal solution.

I have used here $y_i$ for the slack variables.

Comment: so the set will be the convex combination of this solution and (0,1,0,4)? That should be unbounded then:) Many thanks, calculus! How could you get this optimal solution though? I always thought if the matrix A has dimension $2x4$, the vector containing basic variable must have size 2x2?

Comment: did you use the insight that $x_{1}-x_{2}$=-1 is the minimum value of z, then plug it backward to realize that $x_{3}=0$, and finally, choose $x_{4}$ s.t $x_{4}-x_{2}$=3? So basically, any points on the line $x_{1}-x_{2}=1$ is the optimal solution?

Comment: I have problems to say optimal solutions. In the question it is stated, that the set is unbounded. Thus there is no optimal solution like a specific combination or a line. You can name some solutions by calculating feasible solutions. For example (x_1,x2)=(100,49) holds for both restrictions. To visualize the problem you can solve both restriction for $x_2$ and draw them in a $x_1-x_2$-coordinate system.  $$+$$To show that the set is unbounded you can calculate the intersection of $-x_1+x_2=1$ and $x_1-2x_2=2$. If one of the values or both are negativ you don´t have a bounded set.

Comment: The 1st condition implies that $z\geq -1$, so any point lies on the line $x_{1} - x_{2}=-1$ is good, because it then immediately satisfies the 2nd restriction and gives $z=-1$. I think the problem HAS optimal solution. Btw, by the set, I meant the set of optimal solution, not the feasible region:) The feasible region is also unbounded in this case though.

Comment: What would be, in your opinion, an optimal solution ?

Comment: any points on the line $x_{1}-x_{2}=-1$, as the math I just showed. Btw, optimal solution here for MIN problem, not Max

Comment: After I have checked (argh), that the function has to be minimized I agree to your solution.

Comment: No problem:) Your optimal solution did help me look back into the given conditions. Anyway, can you please give a try at this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938601/linear-programming-tableau-condition

Comment: At the moment I can only approve your solution of (a) and (b). I´m not sure about the other solutions.

Comment: Thank you, Calculus:) I thought it was an easy problem, but probably it wasn't. Can you give part (d) a try though? I only know $a<0$, but couldn't find other conditions:(